# laravel check value in other table and if not exist return it

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have two tables.

**access table**

`field acceskey`

**Users Table**

`field acceskey default to null`

In table1 I have 500 rows already
In user I have 10 rows

Now I want to check in Users if there is no acceskey is being use. from the access table.

**Sample entry**
**Access table**

`55`
`56`
`57`
`58`
`59`

**Users Table**

'55'
'null'
'null'
'null'

the accesskey in users table is default to null, so only 1 user have access key.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you provide sample entry ?

Comment: @AshokDevatwal, ok I updated now

Answer (score 0):

You have to join your user table with access table with condition 
where user's access key not match in access's access key
now result will be unique that not have user's access key but it include user's null key 
to remove it use select statement 
finely you got result of acceskey that not used.

```
$data = DB::table('user')
    ->leftJoin('access','access.acceskey', '!=', 'user.acceskey')
    ->where('access.acceskey','!=','null')
    ->select('access.acceskey')
    ->get();
```